# how to permanently change ownership of a file?

Tags: filesystem

When I change ownership of `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` with `chown` its ownership changes again to root after system startup.

Comment: Hmmm you are missing a basic concept of Linux: "/sys/" is a virtual system that gets rebuild on boot. You can not change it. Besides that: you should not change files in "/sys/" in the 1st place. You edit these files as "root" (sudo su, password and then vi {file})

Comment: Please read this: http://askubuntu.com/a/341947/15811

Answer (score 0):

Use `chmod`

e.g. to change to executable, do `chmod +x /path/to/file.extension`

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484718/how-to-make-a-file-executable/484719#484719) answer for a guide on `chmod`.

Comment: As stated in the questio: And when he reboots it is set back to root (as it should)...

Comment: @Rinzwind, does `chmod` still let it revert? I thought that it was because he was using `chown`

Comment: please read this: http://askubuntu.com/a/341947/15811 /sys and /proc are NOT actual directories. "Entries in /sys are created by the kernel and by drivers; you cannot just create them from the command-line. (As stated above, you can edit some as root, but you cannot generally make new ones from userspace except by loading kernel modules or otherwise installing drivers or modifying the kernel.)"

Comment: @Rinzwind You learn something new every day! Thankyou!