# /sys/class/baclight folder is empty, leading to blank screen

Tags: screen, backlight

I recently tried to change the default brightness of my ubuntu by echoing values to /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness, and installing xbacklight, as suggested by answers to other questions. However, after booting ubuntu after doing the above, the screen just went blank.

After further checking, I found /sys/class/backlight folder is empty, and I have not been able to add a folder even under root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

[`Sys` is special](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341939/why-cant-i-create-a-directory-in-sys), you won't be able to create folders there (answers in linked question explain why). Per [Fabby's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/578497/72260) to similar question, that would indicate Kernel thinks you have a CRT, therefore you have knobs to adjust brightness and contrast. You may want to search supported hardware to see whether yours is there, or file a bug against kernel.