# Can't change brightness at all

Tags: brightness

Here is what it looks like when I go to the "change brightness" option. I am booting in recovery mode because when I boot to normal Ubuntu mode there is nothing you can see on the screen, I can only hear the login sound.

So I thought I would need to change the  brightness but neither <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> works, nor do I get an option to change the brightness in the settings.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/589574/295286) may be a useful workaround. As for the normal mode, I'd suggest you install different greeter - like lightdm-gtk-greeter

Comment: got this after enter this in terminal bash: /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness: No such file or directory

Comment: what does this say: `ls /sys/class/backlight/`

Comment: it does nothing when i enter ls /sys/class/backlight/

Comment: Did you verify that your <kbd>Fn</kbd>+... keys work? That they weren't hijacked or shadowed?

Comment: Your question may boil down to same case as in "Dell Chromebook 11 - unable to set backlight and /sys/class/backlight/ folder is empty" or in "/sys/class/baclight folder is empty, leading to blank screen". Former has an answer that I partially quoted. You may want to pick it up with answer's author - he might know more.

Comment: well then then is nothings there i can do then cause ubuntu thinks i have a crt but i have to have some brightness cause the screen is really blank on normal ubuntu mode i have to boot it up in recovery also when i hibernate in recovery it kinda opens up in normal ubuntu mode

Comment: got my brightness back http://i.imgur.com/nT0Oaae.png. i booted up in the third option of the advanced settings and i somehow have my brightness back yesss!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Manual way

Works for some systems, though not yours, apparently, since `ls /sys/class/backlight/` shows nothing for you. Sometimes instead of intel_backlight you'll have acpi_video0, or something else.

> You can manually change the brighntess level all the way down (to
>   disable it altogether) by doing `echo 23 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` as a root. "23" is the desired brightness level. If you put "0", 
>   the screen will look blank.

From [Adam Ryczkowski](https://askubuntu.com/users/55241/adam-ryczkowski)'s comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156708/how-to-get-multimedia-keys-working-at-my-asus-n56vz-ubuntu-12-04-notebook#comment350026_223865), which helped my friend in similar case.

### Empty `/sys/class/backlight/` means unrecognized hardware

When I noticed your exchange with @Serg, I thought "why would that folder be empty" and search showed this:

> If `/sys/class/backlight/` is empty, that means that the kernel thinks
>   you have a big bad old CRT attached to the system and that you have to
>   turn the big fat knobs named "Brightness" and "Contrast" on the from
>   to change... well, brightness and contrast...

source: [@Fabby](https://askubuntu.com/users/344926/fabby)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/578497/72260) to another AskUbuntu question.