# Delete files from /sys (ubuntu do not boot normally)

Tags: 14.04, kde

Unfortunately I have placed a file into the /sys folder of my Kubuntu 14.04, and after this my system could not start normally.
I wanted to delete the file in recovery mode with the root options but in this case if I want to enter to /sys it says no such folder exists.
I also tried to open the /sys folder under windows but it is empty :/
How could I delete a file from /sys?

cheers,

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/341939/why-cant-i-create-a-directory-in-sys You are misunderstanding the usage of /sys: "Like /proc and /dev, in Ubuntu and other OSes using the Linux kernel, /sys is a virtual filesystem, what it represents is not real files on your disk (or anywhere)." PLUS I doubt placing a file /sys would create problem.

Comment: ahm thx, no I get it.
Anyway I have found the wrong file at /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
Just deleted it in recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the culprit is in the file you placed there, then we need to see what file and where exactly it was placed, because you may have tweaked some hardware this way.
Otherwise, the content of `/sys`, being purely virtual, is regenerated every boot. So it is already deleted.

Comment: I have found the wrong file at /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d Just deleted it in recovery mode.