# Cannot delete residual system files period, even after changing permissions as root user

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, system, rm

Okay, so I'm having a weird issue where I've already done
`chown -R myuser:myuser folderName` and `chmod 777 -R folderName`

and upon attempting deletion of these files or the folder using `rm -f`, I get a mysterious and incredibly annoying error message:

```
root@delphi:/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles# sudo rm -rf usr.bin.freshclam.0
rm: cannot remove 'usr.bin.freshclam.0/sha1': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'usr.bin.freshclam.0/attach': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'usr.bin.freshclam.0/mode': Operation not permitted
rm: cannot remove 'usr.bin.freshclam.0/name': Operation not permitted
root@delphi:/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles#
```

Even though the folder and all its files are owned by me, the root user, and permissions are set to `rwxrwxrwx` for the directory and all its included files, I simply cannot delete them. WHY??? Help would be appreciated here, I would like full control of my filesystem.

Comment: The following attempt produces this error message: sudo chattr -i /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles/usr.bin.freshclam.0/attach 
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles/usr.bin.freshclam.0/attach

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? AFAIK `/sys` is a dynamically created filesystem representing the kernel-hardware interface - it's not something that you should normally be trying to manipulate "files" on

Comment: see this answer on [Why can't I create a directory in /sys?](http://askubuntu.com/a/341947/527764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/sys` is the mount point for `sysfs` (a form of `tmpfs`), which represents Linux kernel's internal data structure especially used for exporting hardware related parameters, it was introduced in the kernel version 2.6.

The kernel only allows you to do certain predefined operations like reading from a file, or writing to a file to change the value of some parameter on runtime but all these operations can be performed because kernel provides interface to do the operation. Deleting would mean to altering kernel's internal data structure, which is prohibited by the kernel, same goes for creating file in `/sys` (technically, if kernel allows, you can do these too). So deleting (doing `unlink(2)`) a file from `sysfs` is not permitted by the kernel (at least i am not aware of one), irrespective of the permission.

Comment: Thank you so much, I guess I'll just leave it be haha. I couldn't figure out for the life of me why this was happening.